# Proof of Inner Product Inequality

Tags: inner-products

How to show the following :

Given $f:[a,b] \rightarrow  \mathbb R$, $f(a) = f(b) = 0$, f and f' continuous

in the space $\ell_2$ with norm $\|f\| = \sqrt{(\int_a^b f^2)dx}$.

Show $\|f\| \leq \|f'\|\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Cauchy - Schwarz (which was suggested as a method) gives $|\int_a^b f'| \leq \sqrt{\int_a^b f'^2} * \sqrt{b-a}$

But this result seems useless since $|\int_a^b f'|$ is 0

Comment: Please format your question using [MathJaX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/27741).

Comment: how smooth is the function $f$?

Comment: It seems to me you'll also need the fundamental theorem of calculus and fubinit's theorem. But I may be mistaken.

Comment: No it isn't useless since the norm of the derivative is $\int f'^2$ and due to the square this isn't zero except $f$ is a constant function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow my solution does not require both zeros of $f$. I hope it's still correct and I think that one doesn't need bot zeros of $f$.

Let $x\in[a,b]$ be given.
Since $$|f(x)|^2=(|f(a)+\int_a^x f'|)^2 \leq (\int _a^x |f'(s)| ds)^2\leq (\int_a^x |f'(s)|^2 ds) (x-a)$$
we can integrate this term and receive
$$\int_a^b |f(x)|^2 dx \leq \int_a^b (\int_a^x |f'(s)|^2 ds) (x-a) dx \leq ||f'||^2 (b-a)^2/2$$ Taking the root gives the result. Note that we estimated the integral containing $f'$ with choosing $x=b$. This is allowed since the integrand is non-negative.
Note that $$\int_a^b (x-a) dx= \frac{1}{2} (x^2-ax)|_a^b=\frac{1}{2}(b-a)^2$$

If there is an error please tell me

Comment: There's an error somewhere, although I'm not sure where. It seems to me the inequality fails for say $\ln(x)$ on the interval $[1,20]$.

Comment: I follow up until the double integral, but don't see where the two comes from in that last inequality.

Comment: integrate $(x-a)$ with respect to $x$. @JsSchlather. Shouldn't this be the Poincare inequality with the optimal constant that depends only on the domain?

Comment: @JSchlather. It doesn't fail four your example. The interval is large enough to compensate the small norm of $f'$. Such an estimate is often used when handling PDEs

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Yes, I'm sorry I forgot to take the squareroot when I was doing my calculations.